# Find inverse and determinant of a symmetric matrix - for a maximum-likelihood estimation

Tags: matrices, determinants, matrix-inverse

Evaluate the determinant $\det \Omega $ and find the inverse matrix $\Omega^{-1}$ of:

$$\Omega = \begin{bmatrix} \beta_1^2(1+\theta_1^2) & \beta_1 \beta_2 & ... & \beta_1 \beta_{k-1} & \beta_1 \beta_k \\ \beta_2 \beta_1 & \beta_2^2(1+ \theta_2^2) & ... & \beta_2 \beta_{k-1} & \beta_2 \beta_k \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \beta_k \beta_1 & \beta_k \beta_2 & ... & \beta_k \beta_{k-1} & \beta_k^2(1+\theta_k^2) \end{bmatrix}$$

**Application**

I got this problem when attempting to understand the methodology of the [Worldwide Governance Indicators](http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/index.aspx#doc) where the authors specify a log-likelihood function of three unknown parameters to  solve the maximisation at page 97-99 here [Governance Matters VII: Aggregate and Individual Governance Indicators, 1996-2007](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1148386) (page 97-99).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your matrix is diagonal plus rank 1. Use the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) and the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Answer (score 0):

$\Omega =
\begin{bmatrix} 
\beta_1^2(1+\theta_1^2) & \beta_1 \beta_2 & ... & \beta_1 \beta_{k-1} & \beta_1 \beta_k \\ 
\beta_2 \beta_1 & \beta_2^2(1+ \theta_2^2) & ... & \beta_2 \beta_{k-1} & \beta_2 \beta_k \\
 ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 
\beta_k \beta_1 & \beta_k \beta_2 & ... & \beta_k \beta_{k-1} & \beta_k^2(1+\theta_k^2) 
\end{bmatrix}=  
\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_1^2\theta_1^2 & & & \\
    & \beta_2^2\theta_2^2 & & \\
    & & \ddots & \\
    & & & \beta_k^2\theta_k^2\\
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_1 \\
    \beta_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    \beta_k \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_1 \: \beta_2 \: \ldots \:\beta_k
\end{bmatrix}
$